# Error while trying to run Terraform Apply , Web App Authentication Error

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

I get the below error while trying to run Terraform Apply.

```
Error: updating Authentication Settings for App Service "app-cont-sa-fe-predev-cus-bb2e": web.AppsClient#UpdateAuthSettings: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadRequest" Message="Cannot execute the request for site app-cont-sa-fe-predev-cus-bb2e because the site is running on auth version v2." Details=[{"Message":"Cannot execute the request for site app-cont-sa-fe-predev-cus-bb2e because the site is running on auth version v2."},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"BadRequest","ExtendedCode":"04534","Message":"Cannot execute the request for site app-cont-sa-fe-predev-cus-bb2e because the site is running on auth version v2.","MessageTemplate":"Cannot execute the request for site {0} because the site is running on auth version {1}.","Parameters":["app-cont-sa-fe-predev-cus-bb2e","v2"]}}]
    │ 
    │   with azurerm_app_service.fe,
    │   on resources.app.tf line 59, in resource "azurerm_app_service" "fe":
    │   59: resource "azurerm_app_service" "fe" {
```

Can anyone tell me what do i need to change in my below resource block so that i don't get the error. Thanks

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "fe" {
  location            = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.name
  tags                = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.tags
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.default.id
  name                = module.names-web-app-fe.location.app_service.name_unique
  identity { type = "SystemAssigned" }
  auth_settings {
    enabled                       = true
    default_provider              = "AzureActiveDirectory"
    issuer                        = format("https://sts.windows.net/%s/", data.azurerm_client_config.default.tenant_id)
    runtime_version               = "~1"
    token_store_enabled           = true
    unauthenticated_client_action = "RedirectToLoginPage"
    additional_login_params = {
      "response_type" = "code id_token",
      "resource"      = azuread_application.app-fe.application_id
    }
    active_directory {
      client_id         = azuread_application.app-fe.object_id
      client_secret     = azuread_application_password.fe-app-sp-secret.application_object_id
      allowed_audiences = [format("https://%s.azurewebsites.net", module.names-web-app-fe.location.app_service.name_unique)]
    }
  }
  site_config {
    always_on                = true
    app_command_line         = ""
    default_documents        = []
    dotnet_framework_version = "v4.0"
    ftps_state               = "Disabled"
    health_check_path        = ""
    http2_enabled            = true
    linux_fx_version         = "STATICSITE|1.0"
    local_mysql_enabled      = false
    managed_pipeline_mode    = "Integrated"
    min_tls_version          = "1.2"
    #pre_warmed_instance_count = 0
    python_version            = "3.4"
    remote_debugging_enabled  = false
    remote_debugging_version  = "VS2019"
    use_32_bit_worker_process = false
    websockets_enabled        = false
    windows_fx_version        = ""
    cors {
      allowed_origins     = []
      support_credentials = false
    }
  }
  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER"     = "168.63.129.16"
    "WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL" = "1"
  }
}
```

I guess there were changes from Azure side wrt authentication and because of which i am getting this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Terraform*** uses ***`Auth V1 Settings`*** instead of using ***`Auth V2 setting`*** for the Web App. Currently only ***[`Azure CLI cmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/auth?view=azure-cli-latest)*** and ***[`ARM Templates`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/config-authsettingsv2?tabs=json)*** allow the ***`auth_settings_v2`*** to be configured. This might be available in the ***[`upcoming version of azurerm provider i.e. v3.0.0`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/14193)*** as mentioned under ***Feature details: New Data Sources / Resources for App Service & Function Apps*** .

***As for the error which you are getting , I tried creating a App Service in Azure using similar code as yours and it didn't provide any error in the initial creation but after I go to portal and under authentication setting , I upgrade the authentication settings to v2 . I start receiving the same error while trying to update the application from terraform like below :***

[image]

***In order to avoid the error , if you are using terraform to create and manage the web app , then please don't upgrade Web Authentication Settings .***

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right, the error doesn't come initially. It comes only when you upgrade from the portal and then if you run TF again, it throws this. Ok will follow that advise then

Comment: FYI Terraform now supports auth_settings_v2 in azurerm v3.46.
I am having a issue updating my terraform module to support it tho. I want to provide the user the ability to choose auth_settings or auth_settings_v2 or, neither, but I get syntax error because auth_settings_v2 is expecting values when I don't want to pass any auth setting config.

Comment: @DouglasYoung I get a similar experience. I am on 3.50 but it doesnt let me choose auth_settings_v2 it only lets me choose auth_settings.

Comment: @james What do you mean it "doesn't let you 'choose' auth_settings_v2" What is the error you're getting?
I got mine to work a bit better now but not fully tested yet. I'm using dynamic blocks with a null check(if I don't want to set the auth setting) on the for_each.

Comment: the intellisense only lets me choose auth_settings and not auth_settings_v2. I had to upgrade my provider to version 3.50 and just explicitly type auth_settings_v2. Also a few of the documentation on the terraform website on which blocks are optional and required are incorrect lol. for example the login{} block is optional. However, i get a build error saying its required so i just had to add it. I added the following login{token_store_enabled=true} and that login block is nested within auth_settings_v2.

Comment: also if you use the active_directory_v2 block within auth_settings_v2, the documentation says client_secret_setting_name is optional. but it is not and you need to have it or you will get a build error saying that it is required.

Comment: **Isn't there a way to downgrade or revert back the auth setting?**